# Filter Array into sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am building an IOS app based on data within an array - I'm struggling with filtering data into rows - a snippet of my array is as follows -

**ARRAY Data / Array -**

```
sightsObject *sight2 = [[sightsObject alloc] initWithsiteTitle:@"The Beatles Homes" siteSection:@"beatles" siteType:@"Take a glimpse of the fab 4's childhood homes.." siteSubTitle:@"" siteDescription:@"" siteMapUrl:@"" sitePic:@"fabs"];

sightsObject *sight3 = [[sightsObject alloc] initWithsiteTitle:@"The Beatles Gig Venues" siteSection:@"beatles" siteType:@"" siteSubTitle:@"Its not all about the Cavern..." siteDescription:@"" siteMapUrl:@"" sitePic:@"fabs"];

sightsObject *sight4 = [[sightsObject alloc] initWithsiteTitle:@"The Beates Locations" siteSection:@"beatles" siteType:@"" siteSubTitle:@"Stawberry Fields, Penny Lane, Palm House..." siteDescription:@"" siteMapUrl:@"docks" sitePic:@"fabs"]

sightsObject *sight5 = [[sightsObject alloc] initWithsiteTitle:@"Albert Dock" siteSection:@"dock" siteType:@"" siteSubTitle:@"" siteDescription:@"" siteMapUrl:@"" sitePic:@""];

sightsObject *sight6 = [[sightsObject alloc] initWithsiteTitle:@"Keiths Wine Bar" siteSection:@"Restaurants" siteType:@"" siteSubTitle:@"Classic Eatery on Lark Lane" siteDescription:@"" siteMapUrl:@"" sitePic:@""];

self.sightsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: sight2, sight3, sight4, sight5, sight6,nil];
```

**SightsObject.H**
The Header for the SightsObject os as follows -

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface sightsObject : NSObject


@property(strong)NSString *siteTitle;
@property(strong)NSString *siteSection;
@property(strong)NSString *siteType;
@property(strong)NSString *siteSubTitle;
@property(strong)NSString *siteDescription;
@property(strong)NSString *siteMapUrl;
@property(strong)UIImage *sitePic;


-(id)initWithsiteTitle:( NSString *)siteTitleD siteSection:(NSString *)siteSectionD siteType:(NSString *)siteTypeD siteSubTitle:(NSString *)siteSubTitleD siteDescription:(NSString *)siteDescriptionD siteMapUrl:(NSString *)siteMapUrlD sitePic:(NSString *)sitePicD;

@end
```

**ROWS**
I was unsure how to count the amount of data rows that apply to each section - so this is currently hardcoded -

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 8;
}
```

**FILTERING DATA INTO TABLE CELLS**

My issue is that I now dont know how to filter the data into rows - I currently have below (i have two cell types in my tableview) - when run the code displays the relevant data in the correct cells - but repeats the same data for every section - how can I filter it correctly?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"sightsCell";
static NSString *CellIdentifierH =@"headerCell";
NSString * intro = @"intro";
NSString * ArtNoP = @"lower";

sightsObject *b = [self.sightsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
  UITableViewCell *cell;



if ([b.siteSection isEqualToString:intro]) {
    cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierH forIndexPath:indexPath];
    HeaderCell *cellHead = (HeaderCell *)cell;
    cellHead.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cellHead.sightsText.text = b.siteTitle;
    cellHead.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    return cellHead;


}

else{

    cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    sightsCell *cellSights = (sightsCell *)cell;
    cellSights.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cellSights.sightsTitle.text = b.siteTitle;
    cellSights.sightsSubTitle.text = b.siteSubTitle;
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    return cellSights;

      }
 }
```

Comment: What is 'correct'? From your source data, what should be where? Show the header for your `sightsObject` class.

Comment: Hi @Wain Header added above - I mean that I have two custom classes in my table - which I'm fitering into via the if statements above - that part works fine - my issues is that it shows a series of sections with a section header and the same data in each - I want to be able to filter the data into sections - then decide which custom cell it should appear in

Comment: And the important piece of information is `siteSection` in each of the objects currently in your `sightsArray`? Where are the intro items coming from? Why aren't you adding intro sections when the `indexPath.row == 0`?

Comment: The above is only a snippet of the data array, objects with the siteSection intro are available in the full list

Answer (score 1):

I'd change what you're doing. Rather than have one array with a big list of items and a static count of the sections I'd have an array which contains sections, and each section would be another array containing the row items. This could either be created manually (your configuration code would change) or automatically (by iterating over your existing `sightsArray` and running various predicates on it. The choice really depends on how many items you have and how many / where they will come from in the future.

Once you have that, the number of sections is `self.sightsArray.count` and the number of rows in each section is `[self.sightsArray[section] count]` and the row for a section is:

```
sightsObject *b = self.sightsArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
```

I would also use `indexPath.row == 0` as the indication that you should have an intro row because to organise the sections automatically I would keep all of the `siteSection` values the same for each section.